# SQL Server: query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which takes around 4 minutes to execute.

```
DECLARE @tdate DATETIME = '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT c.id AS clid,
       h.id AS hlid,
       h.holdinNo,
       c.cliendID,
       c.clientName,
       h.floor,
       h.connect_radius
FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
       INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h
               ON c.id = h.clid
WHERE  h.status = 1
       AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
       AND c.status = 1
       AND h.type = 'Residential'
       AND h.holdinNo NOT IN (SELECT holdingNo
                              FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill
                              WHERE  year(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate)
                                     AND MONTH(date_month) = MONTH(@tdate)
                                     AND ( update_by IS NOT NULL
                                            OR ispay = 1 ))
```

I found the inner join takes only few seconds.

```
SELECT c.id AS clid,
       h.id AS hlid,
       h.holdinNo,
       c.cliendID,
       c.clientName,
       h.floor,
       h.connect_radius
FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
       INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h
               ON c.id = h.clid
WHERE  h.status = 1
       AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
       AND c.status = 1
       AND h.type = 'Residential'
```

It's the `NOT IN` checking which takes a lot of time. How I can **optimize** this query? For me it's needed to execute the query at least with in minute.

Comment: You have three different guesses as to what the issue is. Upload the XML for the *actual* execution plan so we can see precisely where the issue is

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `WHERE` and `JOIN` clause predicates are sargable. Applying a function to a column (e.g. `YEAR(date_month)`) prevents indexes on the column from being used efficiently.

Try this expression instead to avoid the functions. There are other methods depending on the SQL Server version.

```
WHERE
    date_month >= DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(month, -1, EOMONTH(@tdate)))
    AND date_month < DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(month, 1, EOMONTH(@tdate)))
```

Comment: DATEADD() and EOMONTH() aren't functions?!!! Your code is not consistent with your claims.

Comment: They are functions but they are not being applied to a column. They are being applied on variables

Comment: @MartinSmith, unless I'm missing something, `date_month` looks to be a column name. Functions are also applied to variables in the query.

Comment: my response was to @forpas. Responding to `DATEADD() and EOMONTH() aren't functions?!!!`

Answer (score 1):

Try by replacing `NOT IN` with a `LEFT JOIN` of the table `[db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill` on all the conditions and adding in the WHERE clause `holdingNo is null` so the returned rows are the non matching rows:

```
select c.id as clid, h.id as hlid,h.holdinNo, c.cliendID, c.clientName, h.floor, h.connect_radius 
from [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client as c 
inner join [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding as h 
on c.id= h.clid
left join [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill as b 
on b.holdingNo = h.holdinNo and year(b.date_month) = YEAR(@tdate) and MONTH(b.date_month) = MONTH(@tdate) 
and (b.update_by is not null or b.ispay = 1)
where h.status = 1 and h.connect_radius is not null and c.status=1 and h.type='Residential' and b.holdingNo is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS` and adding an index:

```
WHERE . . . AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill b
                  WHERE b.holdingNo = h.holdingNo AND
                        b.date_month >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@tdate), MONTH(@tdate), 1) AND
                        b.date_month < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@tdate), MONTH(@tdate), 1)) AND
                        (b.update_by IS NOT NULL OR b.ispay = 1
                 )
```

Then the index that you want is on `tbl_bill(holdingNo, date_month, update_by, ispay)`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your sub query into temp table :

```
DECLARE @tdate DATETIME = '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT holdingNo 
into #TmpholdingNo
FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill
WHERE  year(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate)
        AND MONTH(date_month) = MONTH(@tdate)
        AND ( update_by IS NOT NULL
        OR ispay = 1 )

SELECT c.id AS clid,
       h.id AS hlid,
       h.holdinNo,
       c.cliendID,
       c.clientName,
       h.floor,
       h.connect_radius
FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
       INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h
               ON c.id = h.clid
WHERE  h.status = 1
       AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
       AND c.status = 1
       AND h.type = 'Residential'
       AND h.holdinNo NOT IN (SELECT holdingNo from #TmpholdingNo) 

drop table #TmpholdingNo
```

Answer (score 0):

put the filter list at variable,then them apply the filter

```
     DECLARE @filter TABLE  INSERT INTO @filter SELECT  FROM  [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill
```

them apply the filter

```
DECLARE @tdate DATETIME = '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT c.id AS clid,
       h.id AS hlid,
       h.holdinNo,
       c.cliendID,
       c.clientName,
       h.floor,
       h.connect_radius
FROM [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h ON c.id= h.clid
WHERE h.status=1
  AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
  AND c.status=1
  AND h.type='Residential'
  AND h.holdinNo NOT IN (filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using functions in your `WHERE` clause try calculating the start and end filter dates, using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` can help SQL to use the actual values of your variables in your query plan. I would also change `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @tdate DATETIME = '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @startDate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@tdate), MONTH(@tdate), 1)
DECLARE @endDate DATE = DATEADD(day,1,EOMONTH(@tdate))


SELECT c.id AS clid,
       h.id AS hlid,
       h.holdinNo,
       c.cliendID,
       c.clientName,
       h.floor,
       h.connect_radius
FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
       INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h
               ON c.id = h.clid
WHERE  h.status = 1
       AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
       AND c.status = 1
       AND h.type = 'Residential'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT holdingNo
                       FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill
                       WHERE  holdingNo = h.holdinNo AND
                       date_month >= @startDate AND
                       date_month < @endDate AND 
                                     AND ( update_by IS NOT NULL
                                            OR ispay = 1 )) 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try try this:

```
select main.* from 

    (SELECT c.id AS clid,
           h.id AS hlid,
           h.holdinNo,
           c.cliendID,
           c.clientName,
           h.floor,
           h.connect_radius
    FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_client AS c
           INNER JOIN [db_land].[dbo].tx_holding AS h
                   ON c.id = h.clid
    WHERE  h.status = 1
           AND h.connect_radius IS NOT NULL
           AND c.status = 1
           AND h.type = 'Residential')main

left join 

    (select holdingNo from 
        (SELECT holdingNo, update_by, ispay
        FROM   [db_land].[dbo].tbl_bill
        WHERE  year(date_month) = YEAR(@tdate)
        AND MONTH(date_month) = MONTH(@tdate))bill1
    where update_by IS NOT NULL OR ispay = 1)bill2

on main.holdinNo = bill2.holdinNo


where bill2.holdinNo is null
```